# VS2015 extension - Get selected items in Error list

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to make an extension for Visual Studio 2015 that depends on the selected items in the Error List view.

I'm retrieving the list with the following code:

```
var errorList = this.dte2.ToolWindows.ErrorList as IVsTaskList2;
IVsEnumTaskItems items;
errorList.EnumSelectedItems(out items);
```

But my problem is now that i'm able to get the description (Text) but not the error code (HelpKeyword).
The description do i get this way:

```
 IVsTaskItem[] item = new IVsTaskItem[1];
 while (items.Next(1, item, null) == 0)
 {
    string description;
    item.get_Text(out description);
 }
```

Hope someone can helped me on this as i'm quiet frustrated at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this using a completely different approach:

```
            var errorList = dte.ToolWindows.ErrorList as IErrorList;
            var selected = errorList.TableControl.SelectedEntry;
            if (selected != null)
            {
                object content;
                if (selected.TryGetValue("errorcode", out content))
                {
                    return (string)content;
                }
            }
```

This accesses the error window selected item as a table and just gets the correct column (the text column has key "text", BTW).

It certainly wasn't easy to figure this out. Thank you Microsoft for: 1) the almost total lack of documentation for any of this stuff, 2) completely breaking the interfaces that worked in VS2013, and 3) not simply adding the code as a property for ErrorItem.

Comment: It can be a lonely feeling when you think you are the only programmer on earth trying to do something specific. But this tip helped me out, so there are at least two of us.